# Create Dynamic SQl and Oracle Connections in SSIS-- edited

Tags: ssis

I have a requirement where i need to use 2 different sources(SQl server , Oracle) to pull my data. I am able to create dynamic connection, if source is SQl server,but not sure how to make dynamic connection for oracle.

Note : in future i may have more source systems (sql, oracle, excel, flat file).

How to create all these connection managers in a plug in way(re-usable).

**Question edited**

I was looking for something like, my packgae has 2 DFt's. DFT1 with sql server connection and dft 2 with oracle connection. If data is coming from oracle source i need to moved to dft2, else if it from sql i need to move to DFT1.

What i tried,
i can do this by using an variable which holds the value of Provider(i.e. if provider is MSDAORA then i can move to DFT2 else to DFT1)

I need to pass provider detail into my Package varibale and used that variable. I need to know how to do that in script task.

And also let me know if any other scenario was there for this approach.

Comment: what do you mean by *dynamic* connection ? the connection string is variable ?

Comment: Yes, connection string variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think these links will help you :

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic705191-148-1.aspx

http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.in/2010/07/dynamic-database-connection-using-ssis.html

use script code and create variables for both your connections and provider names also  pass all to the script task as input parameters and than use this code:

```
    Dim constring As String = Dts.Variables("Provider").Value.ToString
    if("'") 
    set your connection string to dfst1
   else
     dfst2
```